# React and dexie: "Invalid hook call" error in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, indexeddb, react-functional-component, dexie

I'm getting the following error when using the useLiveQuery hook from dexie with react. Don't understand, none of the three cases below apply.

The error:

> application.78bb5802.js:58032 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the >body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The component (Editor.js):

```
import React, { useState}  from "react";
import Title from './Title'
import Blocks from './Blocks'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useLiveQuery } from "dexie-react-hooks";
import db from '../db'

const Editor = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    console.log("Editor: start - title state: " + title);

    const tag = useLiveQuery(
        () =>
          title
            ? db.tags.where('name').equals(title)
            : db.tags.toCollection().first(),
        [title]
    );
       
    if(!tag) {
        console.log("tag not loaded yet, returning null");
        return null;
    }

    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        db.tags.where({ name: title }).modify((item) => item.name=event.target.value)
    }
     
    const EditorStyle = styled.section`
        padding: 10px;
        min-width: 400px;
    `;
    console.log("Rendering with title:" + title + " and tag.name: " + tag.name);
    return (
        <EditorStyle>
            <Title 
                onTitleChange={onTitleChange}
                title={tag?.name}
            />
            <Blocks 
                tag={tag?.name}
            />
        </EditorStyle>
    )
}

export default Editor;
```

The database (db.js)

> db.version(1).stores({
> tags: `&name, *tags`,
> blocks: `tag, content`
> });

The db is prepopulated with one value

> db.tags.add({name: "First page"});

Using react 17.0.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: One problem is that the line ’db.tags.where('name').equals(title)’ doesn't return a promise. Add ’.first()' to make it return the first match. That should not give the react hook problem though. Might be a bundling issue. Could you try creating a repro on codesandbox, stackblitz or similar?

Comment: sure, thanks for the help, see with an example. The error is different though...https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-field-1k4l6?file=/src/Editor.js

Answer (score 0):

You need dexie@>3.1.0-alpha.5 right now to use dexie-react-hooks.

Comment: Hi, I'm using dexie hooks version 3.1.0-alpha.6

Comment: The codesandbox sample has dexie@3.0.3 and dexie-react-hooks@1.0.2. I upgraded dexie to 3.1.0-alpha.6 and didn't get the error. Don't see any content yet though.

Comment: Please add additional comments if you're still having issues. Please provide an updated codesandbox link and a description of what is going wrong, if so.

Comment: Hi David, thx, I've started a new version of my project and everything works as expected. Don't know where the error comes from but it is gone now. Thanks for you help!